# iMac WiFi issue

Tags: hardware, imac, wifi

I leave my iMac (24') on almost 24/7, putting it to sleep while not in use. Sometimes when I resume from sleep I encounter the following:

1. WiFi shows full signal
2. Loading web page in Safari loads slowly then stops
3. WiFi sometimes shows degraded signal at this point, but sometimes it doesnt
4. I disable then enable the Airport using the icon at the top of the screen
5. WiFi works as expected

Rebooting the computer fixes this issue, but it is becoming annoying. Is it a know issue, and can it be resolved?

Comment: What type of Wifi router is the iMac connecting to? Is it the only device connected to the router when the issue occurs?

Comment: I forget what brand it is (net gear I think), but we have the iMac, a MacBook, MacBook pro, four iPhones, and the iPad connected to it, and the iMac is the only device experiencing this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to check "Disconnect when logging out" on the *Advanced* preferences of Airport :

[image: airport]

Comment: Havent been having any issues lately, so marking as answer :) Thanks you Studer.

Comment: I have not encountered the issue again since implementing this solution. I am confident that it is a winner :-)